# Watching for changes in angular-chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a request to a rethinkdb database, grabbing the info and doing a couple manipulations to it so that I have the information I need, and then populating a line chart with data. I am using the angular-chart.js directive, and my issue is that I need to basically re-render the chart after the data manipulations complete. Is there a way that I can do this with a watcher?

```
  $scope.things = [];
  $scope.chartData = ChartService.getAll();
  setTimeout(function() {
    var length = $scope.chartData.$$state.value.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      $scope.things[i] = angular.copy($scope.chartData.$$state.value.data[i].State);
    }
    console.log("Things: " + $scope.things);
    var object = {};
    var array = $scope.things;
    for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
      object[array[i]] = (object[array[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
    console.log("Object: " + JSON.stringify(object));
    $scope.labels = [object];
    console.log("Labels: " + $scope.labels);
  }, 2000);
```

So I create an empty array, then make a call to my service and push the data I get back into the array. Then I run a for loop on it to add the number of each array element (in this case I am getting back different state abbreviations) to an object. The object looks something like {"AZ": 1, "OH": 5, etc....}. Basically then I need the graph to re-render at this point with the new data. I assumed a watcher would be the answer but any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the ChartService return a promise. This will let you do your manipulations/rendering after you get your data.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ChartController', function($scope, ChartService) {
  ChartService.getAll().success(function(chartData) {
    $scope.chartData = chartData;
    // do you data manipulations here
    // call your chart renderer here
  });
});

app.factory("ChartService", function($http) {
  var service = {};

  service.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get("api/states").success(function(states) {
      // do some stuff
    })
  }

  return service;
})
```

Comment: Ahhh yes you are right. I was using a service for it but I was not using the promise properly. Good solution, thanks!